# Annual subscription for Excel applications

Tags: excel, passwords, subscription, vba

I design Excel spreadsheets for small tax and accounting agencies (1-10 employees). These spreadsheets provide them with easy and accurate calculation of deprications, dividing profit over stakeholders or calculation of car taxes. Every client has its own spreadsheet and for every year a new tab/sheet is created. The sheets contain some simple VBA and macro's to allow some automation.

So far so good.

I know how to use password protection. But I lack knowledge of conditional protection. I would like to see that my clients need to purchase a code that allows to use the spreadsheets the new year.

I was thinking of sending them a simple code, built in a stand-alone spreadsheet or even a simple .txt file. But secondly, every spreadsheet should have a built-in function that disallows use of any year beyond the current one.

So practically, if a client pays for next year subscription, I send them an unlock file (either by mail or teamviewer) and subsequently they can use all their spreadsheets for another year. Maybe needless to explain, but in all cases the old information stored in the spreadsheets must may available at all times, regardless state of the subscription. So printing and making recalculations for 2014-15-16 must be possible but not for 2017.

I'm sorry for this long piece of text. But grateful for any help.

Dennis
The Netherlands

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? If you want somebody to write code for you, you probably misunderstood the concept and purpose of this site. We are here to help you in some particular programming issues. If you want somebody to make some commercial project for you, there are tons of VBA experts on classified sites like Gumtree where I came from, I'm sure they are also in Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you licensed the file for 2016. Let TODAY be the day the file is opened.

You can write a macro to check the year of TODAY, if it is 2016 then let the password be the 2016 password (and the user can use it, since he has it), if the year is no longer 2016 then lock the file with another password that the user does not have.

Comment: Thanks, this idea makes sense. My solution sofar will now comprise a Master Workbook and a Slave Workbook. The Master will contain license information, basically an array with calender years. It will be placed on a hidden sheet which can only be opened by myself.

Comment: The Slave Workbook will refer to the Master Workbook. If the licensed year is not present in the array, all year based formula's will not work or will be crippled. 

Any customer can make as many copies of the Slave Workbook as they want. I only need their Master Workbook to update annual subscription.
In addition I may need some simple VBA codes to hide some sheets (VBA code : very hidden).

I realise that Excel cannot be protected very thoroughly but that is not so imported for the moment.

Comment: @Dennis, if the answer was useful consider marking it as such. That's how we show appreciation here ;)